# How can i make protocol implementation as argument of function

Tags: swift

How do i create Protocol as an argument of function.

In Android java, we can make an argument of interface like this.

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClicklistener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
});
```

But how do i do same thing in Swift.
For example, i have following Protocol, how can i pass protocol while constructing it.

```
protocol ButtonListener
{
    func onClick()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a  misunderstanding for what you should use to achieve it. Probably you want to pass a *closure* as a parameter to the function.

Citing from [the Swift programming language - Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html):

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed
>   around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks
>   in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

Example:

```
protocol Foo {
    func myFunc(onClick: (_ myView: UIView) -> Void)
}

class MyClass: Foo {
    func myFunc(onClick: (UIView) -> Void) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here we have a `Foo` protocol contains `myFunc` which has a closure parameter of type `(UIView) -> Void`.

Therefore:

```
let object = MyClass()

object.myFunc { view in
    // you can access `view` here as:
    view.backgroundColor = ...
    view.frame = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, these single-method protocols, as event handlers are not necessary. In Swift, you can create any kind of *closure* type you want.

Your `onClick` method can be represented by the closure type `() -> Void` (accepts no parameters and returns `Void`). Instead of `setOnClickListener` as a method, you can just declare `onClick` as a property:

```
var onClick: (() -> Void)?
```

And then you can set it just like you would with any other property:

```
onClick = {
    print("I am clicked!")
}
```

To call `onClick`, you can unwrap it first to make sure it's not nil:

```
if let onClick = self.onClick {
    onClick()
}
// or
onClick?()
```

If you are familiar Java 8, closure types are kind of like functional interfaces, except you get more freedom with closure types. `Consumer<String>` would correspond to `(String) -> Void`, `Function<String, Integer>` would correspond to `(String) -> Int`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it by protocol.

```
protocol ButtonListener {}

extension ButtonListener where Self: UIView {
    func btnClick() {
        // print func
    }
}
```